# How to do a pre-checkout with Git

Tags: git, githooks, git-checkout

I would like to move some files before doing a `git checkout` on a specific branch, and to execute some scripts.

There is no way to do an alias to checkout with my scripts, I really need a hook.

I saw many links and it seems the the pre-checkout hook is not yet implemented.
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to achieve 'pre-checkout' hook in Git/bitbucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000366/how-to-achieve-pre-checkout-hook-in-git-bitbucket)

Answer (score 0):

you can use git stash that grab your local changes.

Usually i do next:

```
git stash -u; 
git checkout <branch>; 
git stash pop
```

Execute them in one line with && and you will get way to move your changes across branches.

```
git stash -u && git checkout <branch> && git stash pop
```

Comment: Just an FYI: that strategy doesn't always work.  In particular, if there are no changes to be stashed, `git stash pop` may end up popping a previous set of changes you had stashed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git stash´ may be that you want.

[Git Tools - Stashing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)