# Can a post-checkout hook check if a single file was being checked out?

Tags: git, githooks, post-checkout-hook

I'm writing a post-checkout hook, but I'd like to avoid it being run if certain conditions are met, with one of these being upon checkout of a single touched file. For example, I'd like it to run if I run `git checkout somebranch`, but avoid it being run if I just want to `git checkout -- some/touched/file`.

As far as I know, the `post-checkout` script is only passed the previous and post-checked-out commit hashes, with some additional data being scrapable from the git repo's global state, but I'm not sure what to check to figure out if it's just a single file being checked out.

Is this possible at all? If so how?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44427629/7976758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter for [post-checkout hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout) is 1 for branch checkout or 0 for file checkout but there is no way to learn what files just have been checked out.

The only way that comes to my mind — scan the entire worktree and collect files that have modification date very close to the current time (within a few seconds).

Comment: Just knowing whether or not the checkout is a file checkout is sufficient in this script, but thanks a lot for suggesting how to figure out which file's being checked out!